# Multicast from tcp replay seen by wireshark but not by application

Tags: python, udp, multicast

I have got a multicast packet capture I'm playing with tcpreplay:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
tcpreplay -i eth0 --loop=100 new.pcap
```

I watch the traffic on eth0 with wireshark and I can see the packets I'm interested in (let's say 224.0.23.60:4937).

But the following python app cannot find the packets:

```
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '224.0.23.60'
MCAST_PORT = 4937

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))  # use MCAST_GRP instead of '' to listen only
                         # to MCAST_GRP, not all groups on MCAST_PORT
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
   print '#'
   print sock.recv(64)
```

netstat -g is giving the following output:

```
lo              1      all-systems.mcast.net
eth0            1      224.0.23.60
```

Am I missing something here ?

[Edit] I should precise that the ip src in my packet capture is not in the same network subdomain (ip src: 192.168.1.10) whereas my ip is something like 146.186.197.164.

Comment: tcpreplay? I thought multicast is UDP only?

Comment: Well apparently tcpreplay is able to play udp packets, because I can see the udp mulitcast packets in wireshark.

Comment: Your app sending nothing [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607516/python-udp-broadcast-not-sending)

Comment: @dsgdfg My app is only listening, traffic is generated by tcpreplay with packet capture (pcap).

Answer (score 2):

After reading carefully the documentation (http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/FAQ), it seems that tcpreplay sends the packets between the TCP/IP stack and the ethernet device driver, therefore the TCP/IP stack of the host system never sees the packets.

I ended up using a debian Os with virtual box configured with the host only adapter and use tcpreplay in that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it is mentioned clearly on the FAQ page.

https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/faq.html#can-i-send-packets-on-the-same-computer-running-tcpreplay

> Q: Can I send packets on the same computer running tcpreplay?
>
> Generally speaking **no**. When tcpreplay sends packets, it injects them
> between the TCP/IP stack of the system and the device driver of the
> network card. The result is the TCP/IP stack system running tcpreplay
> never sees the packets.
>
> **One suggestion** that has been made is using something like VMWare,
> Parallels or Xen. Running tcpreplay in the virtual machine (guest)
> would allow packets to be seen by the host operating system.